# Navigate the DOM within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a nested table where I want to toggle collapsing of details for a row when I click on an icon in the first cell of the row. The showing/hiding of the details work, but I am not able to toggle the icon between + and -.

Here is the table

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Orders) {
      <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggleButton">
                <i class="fa fa-plus" style="display: table-cell"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus" style="display: none"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNumber)
        </td>                    
      </tr>
      <tr class="orderLines" style="display: none">
        <td colspan="999">
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    ...
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
```

and here is the code where I show hide, the details, but I am not able to figure out how to navigate so I can show/hide the +/- icons.

```
    function a() {
            var elements = $(".toggleButton");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].onclick = function() {
                    var orderLines = $(this).closest('tr').next('.orderLines'); //
                    if (orderLines !== 'undefined') {
                        var a = $(this).firstChild;     //Shouldn't this point at first <i>?
                        var td = $(this).closest('td'); //This points at the <td> holding the <a class="toggleButton">
                        var a2 = td.children;           //Yet this is still undefined
                        //var minus = $(this).closest('td').next();
                        var attr = orderLines.attr("style");
                        if (attr.indexOf("none") !== -1) {
                            orderLines.attr("style", "display: table-row");
                            //plus.attr("style", "display: none");
                            //minus.attr("style", "display: table-cell");
                        } else {
                            orderLines.attr("style", "display: none");
                            //plus.attr("style", "display: table-cell");
                            //minus.attr("style", "display: none");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Inside the .onclick `$(this).find(".fa").toggle()`

Comment: You're mixing up when you have a jquery object and when you are looking at the DOM.  eg `td.children` where td is a jquery object should be `td.children()`  / `.firstChild` isn't a property of a jquery object, perhaps `$(this).firstChild` should be `this.firstChild` or `$(this).children().first()`

Comment: Thanks, the $(this).find(".fa").toggle() does exactly what I want